# Using Jquery for retrieving data submitted in login box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this form, and i want to retrieve the data submitted in the password and id

fields in order to see i this is a legal user using Jquery:

```
   <form>
   <div id="login" align="right" > 
   Password: <input type="password" id="pass"/>
   Username: <input type="text" name="name" value="User" id="user"/>
   <input type="submit" id="send" value=" Send " class="submit" />
   <hr color='black'/>

   </div> 
   </form>
```

any ideas what should be written in the js file?

EDIT:

i have a fixed and single password and user name, lets say they are both 'admin'

Comment: Do you want to pass this data to the server and get a response to see if the user is authorized to proceed or are you asking about how to pass the username and password to the server?

Comment: Look up jQuery's AJAX functions. You make the request to another script on your server using AJAX, and simply send the two values as a query string. You shouldn't send it in clear text--it should be sent using https. Lookup jQuery/AJAX. There's plenty of documentation.

Comment: Define "legal" as this could mean a number of things. Did you mean not empty ? Or would you like to perform server validation via an ajax request ?

Comment: It's considered good form to at least try it for yourself and ask for help with specific issues. A little bit of effort and sample code (even if it's half-baked) will go a long way for getting the best possible help from SO users.

Comment: i have a fixed single user and password and i want to see if the data is right. lets say its 'admin' and 'admin'...

Comment: @Itzik984 I hope you plan on using a web service or post to server to validate a "fixed single user/password". Put that into javascript and I'll find it and log into your site.

Comment: @MatthewCox im just trying to learn how to do that... no website is about to go on air soon...

Comment: @Itzik984 You should clarify your question then. So far it's not really clear what you are trying to do with it once you grab it through jquery.

Comment: @MatthewCox im trying to hide some info on my html file.
if the user and password are both 'admin' then the hidden info will be accesible...

Comment: check out `jquery.validate.js`

Comment: @Itzik984 The problem with that approach is that it isn't really hidden. All I have to do is load up fire bug or dev tools and I can place a display: block, style on said hidden content and bypass your security all together.

Comment: @MatthewCox i agree,but again, this is for learning purpose only... im not gonna make a web page with this approach

Comment: @Itzik984 Ahhh, learning purposes. Okay, fair enough. Just wanted to make sure you understand the ramifications. =P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
$('body').on('submit', 'form', function(e){
    valid = true;
    if ($('#pass').val() != 'admin') valid = false;
    if ($('#user').val() != 'admin') valid = false;

    if (valid) {
        alert('Correct Login');
        $('body').off('submit');
        $(this).submit();
    }
    else {
        alert('Incorrect Login');
        return false;  
    }
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/paD2s/5/

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Grabbing the values from the form is as simple as using $('#id').val() - After you've retrieved the data, you can validate it however you see fit. Something like this maybe

-- Disclaimer: not tested --

```
$('#send').click(function(e){
  var user = $('#user').val(),
      pass = $('#pass').val();

  if( user !== 'admin' || pass !== 'admin' ){
     e.preventDefault()
  } else {
    // submit the form
  }
})
```